# Multiple auth providers at the same time using ember-simple-auth

Tags: ember.js, ember-simple-auth

Is it possible to use ember-simple-auth with multiple auth providers at the same time? For example, in my website I want to call few google analytic APIs using google's JWT auth token and other APIs using custom oauth2 token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have few authenticators, but use only one authenticator at the time. It's mentioned in [docs](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth#authenticators). So the answer is no. It's because you have only one session service, which holds authentication status. And I don't see a way of solving this without heavily modifying ember-simple-auth.